# icons, which are equally distributed across the grid

Tags: css, html, grid, material-design, flexbox

Is it possible to equally distribute the icons using only CSS?

I want to get this result (I have not reputation to post images)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC0Aw.jpg

I found a solution using javascript:

```
_http://jsfiddle.net/VLr45/59
```

I tried flexbox, but got this

```
http://jsfiddle.net/egns7cj1/
http://jsfiddle.net/egns7cj1/2/
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8tU2.jpg

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I added links to jsfiddle

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/egns7cj1/3/

Comment: @ManojKumar items should be placed from left to right  http://i.stack.imgur.com/M6alC.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the items inside another parent which would have `flex-basis: 33%`. Change the value based on the screen size using media queries.

```css
.flex-container {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px #eee solid;
  background: #ffd54f;
}
.inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px #777 solid;
}
@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .inner-container {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .inner-container {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Using this method we have a fixed number of columns: column 33% - 3 columns, 25% - 4 columns, etc. Is there a way to have a floating number of columns, depending on the width

Comment: as when using 
`justify-content: space-between`